# Apportioning Rules for Paired Transactions using R Data Frame

Tags: r, dplyr

A tricky problem which I'd like to solve without using a `for()` loop in R because the full dataset I'm using is very large and it would take forever to execute. Imagine the following data:

```
df_z <- data.frame(z_index       = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4),
                   z             = c(800, 800, 800, 310, 310, 310, 763, 763, 763, 3621, 3621),
                   paired_type   = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "F", "A", "B", "D", "C", "F"),
                   paired_amount = c(0, 1768, 3973, 40, 100, 22, 461, 0, 1499, 10817, 0))
```

This shows 4 different `z` amounts (`800`, `310`, `763` and `3621`). For each of these I have a number of amounts, each of which has an `paired_type` - `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. I'd like to go through each row, gradually "spending" the `z` amount on reducing the paired amounts, until `z_amount` has reduced to `0`. This process needs to be done in order of the offset_type ie `A` first, then `B`, then `C`, etc.

So for `z_index` = 2 for example, I start with `z = 310` and I'd like to "spend" 40 on `paired_type` `A`, another `100` on `paired_type` `B` and another `22` on `paired_type` `C`, leaving me with `148` left over at the end.

It's quite easy to do in a spreadsheet:

[image]

but how to turn it into a piece of R code is not obvious to me...

I should add: I don’t just need to know the z amount afterwards, I also need to know each of the paired amounts (ie the final column in the spreadsheet).

Can anyone help please? `dplyr` based solutions particularly welcome (I speak `dplyr` reasonably well)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you might approach this:

```
library(dplyr)

df_z %>%
  group_by(z_index) %>%
  mutate(z_after_offset = pmax(0, cumsum(if_else(row_number() == 1, z, 0) - paired_amount)),
         z_after = min(z_after_offset),
         paired_amount_after = pmax(0, paired_amount - lag(z_after_offset, default = first(z))))

# A tibble: 11 x 7
# Groups:   z_index [4]
   z_index     z paired_type paired_amount z_after_offset z_after paired_amount_after
     <dbl> <dbl> <fct>               <dbl>          <dbl>   <dbl>               <dbl>
 1       1   800 A                       0            800       0                   0
 2       1   800 B                    1768              0       0                 968
 3       1   800 C                    3973              0       0                3973
 4       2   310 A                      40            270     148                   0
 5       2   310 C                     100            170     148                   0
 6       2   310 F                      22            148     148                   0
 7       3   763 A                     461            302       0                   0
 8       3   763 B                       0            302       0                   0
 9       3   763 D                    1499              0       0                1197
10       4  3621 C                   10817              0       0                7196
11       4  3621 F                       0              0       0                   0
```

Comment: Thank you! I did wonder if cumsum() might make an appearance in a solution. I’ll test this code out shortly.

Comment: In the final column (paired_amount_after) I had expected the first 3 numbers to be 0, 968, 3973 - ie the z = 800 amount is "spent" in reducing the amount on the second row. Have I missed something?

Comment: ditto on row 9 - I had expected paired_amount_after to be 1499 - 302 = 1197

Comment: z_after_offset and z_after seem to be fine though so it's just something about that final column I think. Sorry...if I had the coding skills I'd probably be able to fix it myself! :-(

Comment: Sorry, it was correct then I made a sloppy edit which broke things. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you. I think it works! I've amended the code a bit so that it runs on the actual dataset I'm working on and I've done some spot checks and some checks of the overall totals and all seems well. Sir/Madam, I am most grateful for your kind assistance.